# Ormlite query takes time in Android

Tags: java, android, bulkinsert, ormlite

I am working in Android application in which I am using ormlite. I am taking my phone book contacts and saving them in my local database, but the problem is that it is taking too much time like for almost 1500 contact it is taking almost 70 seconds.

I searched for the Bulk insert in ormlite, but I can't figure it out how to implement it in my following code.

```
public static void loadLocalPhoneBookSample(Context ctx) {

        try{

        ContentResolver contentRes = ctx.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = null;

        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
        cur = contentRes.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTIONS, selection, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        context = ctx;

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

            // create DB object
            MUrgencyDBHelper db = new MUrgencyDBHelper(ctx);
            RuntimeExceptionDao<ContactLocal, ?> contactDAO = db.getContactLocalIntDataDao();

            UpdateBuilder<ContactLocal, ?> updateDAO = contactDAO.updateBuilder();
            try {

                updateDAO.updateColumnValue("isUseless", true);
                updateDAO.update();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
//              db.writeUnlock();
            }


            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                /** read names **/
                String displayName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                /** Phone Numbers **/

                Cursor pCur = contentRes.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                    String number = pCur
                            .getString(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

String formatedNo = number.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replace("+", "00").replace("-", "").trim();

                        try {

                            QueryBuilder<ContactLocal, ?> query = contactDAO.queryBuilder();
                            query.where().eq("mFormatedNumber", number);

                            ContactLocal contact = query.queryForFirst();
                            boolean addContact = false, alreadyUpdated = true;

                            if (contact == null) {
                                addContact = true;
                                contact = new ContactLocal();
                                contact.setFirstName(displayName.trim());
                                contact.setLastName(displayName.trim());
                                contact.setContactNumber(formatedNo);
                            }

                            // check if this contact was already updated before
                            if (contact.getContactNumber() == null || contact.getContactNumber().length() == 0) {
                                contact.setContFirstLastNo(number, displayName, displayName, number);
                                alreadyUpdated = false;
                            }

                            contact.setUseless(false);

                            // if not updated already, Create/Update
                            if (addContact) {
                                contactDAO.create(contact);
                            } else
                                contactDAO.update(contact);
                        } 
                }

                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: One possible optimization is to not query `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` at all. Instead you can query `Phone.CONTENT_URI` and include the contacts columns in the projection. You'll only need this one cursor and not have to make further queries, but you'll have to change your code to look for where each new contact starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the problem is that it is taking too much time like for almost 1500 contact it is taking almost 70 seconds

@CarloB has the right answer in terms of doing the mass creates inside the `dao. callBatchTasks(...)` method.  Here's the docs on that subject:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/batch

To make things a bit faster, you could also go through and record all of the `mFormatedNumber` in another `List` and then query for them using an `IN` query.  Use a raw in query to get back the `mFormatedNumber` that are already in the database:

```
results = dao.queryRaw(
    "SELECT mFormatedNumber from Contact WHERE mFormatedNumber IN ?",
    mFormatedNumberList);
```

For using raw queries with ORMLite, see:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries

So then you would make one query to see which of the contacts need to be created and then do all of the inserts from within a batch transaction.

Otherwise you are doing ~3000 synchronous database transactions and 40/sec on an Android device is unfortunately pretty typical.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my revised version (might need a few syntax changes)

```
public static void loadLocalPhoneBookSample(Context ctx) {
try {
    ContentResolver contentRes = ctx.getContentResolver();
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
    Cursor cur = contentRes.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTIONS, selection, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    context = ctx;

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

        // create DB object
        MUrgencyDBHelper db = new MUrgencyDBHelper(ctx);
        RuntimeExceptionDao<ContactLocal, ?> contactDAO = db.getContactLocalIntDataDao();

        UpdateBuilder<ContactLocal, ?> updateDAO = contactDAO.updateBuilder();
        try {
            updateDAO.updateColumnValue("isUseless", true);
            updateDAO.update();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            //              db.writeUnlock();
        }

        ArrayList<ContactLocal> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            /** read names **/
            String displayName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            /** Phone Numbers **/               
            Cursor pCur = contentRes.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                String number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String formatedNo = number.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replace("+", "00").replace("-", "").trim();

                try {
                    QueryBuilder<ContactLocal, ?> query = contactDAO.queryBuilder();
                    query.where().eq("mFormatedNumber", number);

                    ContactLocal contact = query.queryForFirst();

                    if (contact == null) {
                        contact = new ContactLocal();
                        contact.setFirstName(displayName.trim());
                        contact.setLastName(displayName.trim());
                        contact.setContactNumber(formatedNo);
                    }

                    contact.setUseless(false);
                    contacts.add(contact);
                } 
            }
            pCur.close();

        }
        contactDao.callBatchTasks(new Callable<Void>() {
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                for (ContactLocal contact : contacts) {
                    contactDAO.createOrUpdate(contact);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The main optimization is to use `callBatchTasks`. From the ormlite documentation:

> Databases by default commit changes after every SQL operation. This method disables this "auto-commit" behavior so a number of changes can be made faster and then committed all at once.

By creating an `ArrayList` and keeping track of the changes, you can use `callBatchTasks` to create/update at the end all in one shot.

Also I noticed that `alreadyUpdated` was never accessed, so it's safe to remove.

Also `Dao` has a `createOrUpdate` method which is the same as the `addContact` if statement you had before.